# git submodule update "no-fetch"

Tags: git, git-submodules

When I issue a sub-module update and include "--no-fetch" like so:

```
git submodule update --remote --no-fetch
```

The [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) states:

> In order to ensure a current tracking branch state, update --remote
>   fetches the submodule’s remote repository before calculating the
>   SHA-1. If you don’t want to fetch, you should use submodule update
>   --remote --no-fetch.

I'm a bit confused about the "--no-fetch" part. If I call update without it:

```
git submodule update --remote
```

I understand that a fetch will not be performed - but this also means I am not guaranteed a "*current tracking branch state*" ? What exactly does that mean?

Under what scenario would I not want the guarantee of a *current tracking branch state*?

Answer (score 1):

`git submodule update` does several things under the hood. From `git help submodule`:

> Update the registered submodules to match what the superproject
> expects by cloning missing submodules, fetching missing commits in
> submodules and updating the working tree of the submodules.

So running `git submodule update --remote` is roughly equivalent to (inside the submodule):

```
$ git fetch origin  # update remote-tracking branches
$ git checkout origin/HEAD  # update working tree
```

`origin/HEAD` is a *remote-tracking branch* that follows the branch from the remote repository (it is normally hidden, but you can see it with `git branch --remotes`). Note that the `git fetch` incurs network activity, but the `git checkout` happens entirely locally.

`--no-fetch` skips the first step, but will still update your submodule working tree to the remote tracking branch.

I don't think there is a common situation when you would prefer `--no-fetch`, but it would probably be most useful in situations of limited connectivity. For example, before you go on an airplane, you can `git fetch --recurse-submodules`. Then during the flight you can use `git submodule update --remote --no-fetch` (update to submodule remote-tracking branch) or `git submodule update --no-fetch` (update to commit recorded in superproject) without accessing the network. However this would not have the "current tracking branch state," since your remote-tracking branch will only be as recent as your last fetch.